# Prevent PyCharm from extending sys.path

Tags: python, path, pycharm, pythonpath

It really bugs *(ha.)* me that PyCharm executes scripts ever so slightly differently than plain command line execution. It makes project and package configuration hard for a relative newbie like me.

**Problem**: Every time a script is run, either normally or in the Python console (Run > Edit conf.) the script folder and the project root are automagically appended to `sys.path`. I'd expect either one, but not both.

So, **is there a way to disable or otherwise configure this appending?** I'd like to do it without manipulating the path in the beginning of every executable script, but if there's a way to use a startup script or a run script of some sort, that'd be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to

Run->Edit Configurations

There are, among other things, two checkboxes:

1. Add content root to PYTHONPATH
2. Add source root to PYTHONPATH

that should control the described behaviour of adding the directories to the path.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if I'm just really special in my own kind of way. Wow. Well thanks anyway :D